# Why does Android append a number to installed apk's, i.e. com.company.app-1.apk?

Tags: android, apk, filenames

Why does Android append a number to installed apk's, i.e. com.company.app-1.apk when I install an apk? What is the meaning of the number? I find it irritating becuase I no longer can be sure of what the file is called. What is the logic behind this behaviour?

What exactly is the difference between `pm install app.apk` and `cp app.apk /data/app/` ?

Comment: I think it is happening because you already have same name of apk available in your folder and instead of overriding it . it will copy apk with name append to it.

Comment: Have you enabled multiDex support in your app?

Comment: Why would I have apk already in my folder when I install it the first time? Is it if I reinstall it?

Comment: No. I believe not.